# How to display WebMapServiceImageryProvider with Height on Cesium

Tags: wms, cesium

First of all, I have set the WapMapServiceImageryProvider with Geoserver deploy radar image to the Cesium, The result like this:
[image]

The code is :

`function addRadarHKZindex(physicalHeight){
  if(!activeRadarHeight.hasOwnProperty(physicalHeight)){
    var geoWmsLayer = new Cesium.WebMapServiceImageryProvider({
      url : geoserver_url,
      layers: 'layer_name',
      parameters : {
            service     : 'WMS',
            version     : '1.1.0',
            request     : 'GetMap',
            styles      : radarHeight[physicalHeight],

/* The Geoserver determines style to define the radar height */
            format      : 'image/png',
            transparent : true,
            srs         : 'EPSG:4326',
            width       : '545',
            height      : '768'
        }
    });
    activeRadarHeight[physicalHeight] = imageryLayers.addImageryProvider(geoWmsLayer);
    scene.requestRender();
  }
}`

But the radar image is on the ground with 0 ft, I would like to display WebMapServiceImageryProvider with Physical Height on Cesium.

The idea just like this
[image]

I have tried use Rectangle + height with WebMapServiceImageryProvider but not working, here's the code

`function addRadarHKZindex(physicalHeight){
  if(!activeRadarHeight.hasOwnProperty(physicalHeight)){
    var tmp_rectangle = Cesium.Rectangle.fromDegrees(111.32, 19.8, 117.24, 25.9);
    tmp_rectangle.height = physicalHeight;`

```
var geoWmsLayer = new Cesium.WebMapServiceImageryProvider({
  url : geoserver_url,
  layers: 'layer_name',
  rectangle : tmp_rectangle, // Add physicalHeight into rectangle
  parameters : {
        service     : 'WMS',
        version     : '1.1.0',
        request     : 'GetMap',
        styles      : radarHeight[physicalHeight],
```

/* The Geoserver determines style to define the radar height */
            format      : 'image/png',
            transparent : true,
            srs         : 'EPSG:4326',
            width       : '545',
            height      : '768'
        }
    });
    activeRadarHeight[physicalHeight] = imageryLayers.addImageryProvider(geoWmsLayer);
    scene.requestRender();
  }
}

However, the result is not working, the result is showing grey rectangle:
[image]

so How to display WebMapServiceImageryProvider with Height on Cesium correctly?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: OK, I will explain more.